# Opera & IE: cursor auto doesn't work

Tags: css, sass

I have the cursor set to pointer on a parent element, and reset it by using cursor:auto on the child. This doesn't seem to work in Opera and IE11.

```
#lightbox{
    cursor: pointer;

    #lbContent{
        cursor: auto;
    }
}
```

A jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/djAcU/

Comment: JSfiddle might be useful

Comment: I added one to the question :)

Comment: Does seem to be a bug. It looks like auto is being treated as inherit in IE11 (I can't test Opera).

Comment: Any update on this? MS Edge seems to treat this the same way.

Comment: I added a petition on uservoice for MS Edge. Please vote if this bothers you too: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9571605-stop-treating-cursor-auto-like-cursor-inherit